# Regular Expression with Groups and Values in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex to convert some two digit years to four digit years in a pipe delimited file.  I am using:

```
Regex dateFormat = new Regex(@"\|(\d\d)/(\d\d)/([\d\d)\|");
string convertedString = dateFormat.Replace(contents, @"|$1$220$3|'");
```

What I want is |10/31/09| to be replaced with |10312009|.

What I am getting is |10$22009|

I think the problem is .NET is evaluating $1 and $3 but is thinking there is a group in the middle with no value ($220 maybe?).  How can I let .NET know that the 20 is a constant value instead of part of the group value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you a `[` slipped past you in the regex...

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition about the problem is correct: the second backreference is being interpreted as `$220`, not `$2`. To fix this, use curly braces:

```
dateFormat.Replace(contents,@"|$1${2}20$3|'");
```

More info about .NET regular expressions is available [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your regex text doesn't parse.  Was the "[" supposed to be there?  Wrap the number in {} to fix the replace issue:

```
Regex dateFormat = new Regex(@"\|(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)\|");
string convertedString = dateFormat.Replace(contents, @"|${1}${2}20${3}|'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Regex to use named groups instead.  The syntax for a named group is (?).  Then, in your Replace function you can use the group names instead of the group number.

```
Regex dateFormat = new Regex(@"\|(?<month>\d\d)/(?<day>\d\d)/(?<year>[\d\d)\|");
string convertedString = dateFormat.Replace(contents, @"|${month}${day}20${year}|'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that but here is my workaround. To use named group.

```
Regex dateFormat = new Regex(@"\|(?<month>\d\d)/(?<date>\d\d)/(?<year>\d\d)\|");
string convertedString = dateFormat.Replace(contents, @"|${month}${date}20${year}|'");
```

See more infor at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx).

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually, he used `<pre>` tags to format the code, and the group names got interpreted as tags.  @NawaMan, to format code, just indent it four spaces (or select it and press `CTRL-k`).

Comment: You can check the preview below the entry area to see how it will look before posting...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string contents = "|10/31/09|";
Regex dateFormat = new Regex(@"\|(?<mm>\d\d)/(?<dd>\d\d)/(?<yy>\d\d)\|");
Console.WriteLine(dateFormat.Replace(contents, "|${mm}${dd}20${yy}|"));
```

More information:

> Call RegexObj.Replace("subject", "replacement") to perform a search-and-replace using the regex on the subject string, replacing all matches with the replacement string. In the replacement string, you can use $& to insert the entire regex match into the replacement text. You can use $1, $2, $3, etc... to insert the text matched between capturing parentheses into the replacement text. Use $$ to insert a single dollar sign into the replacement text. To replace with the first backreference immediately followed by the digit 9, use ${1}9. If you type $19, and there are less than 19 backreferences, the $19 will be interpreted as literal text, and appear in the result string as such. To insert the text from a named capturing group, use ${name}. Improper use of the $ sign may produce an undesirable result string, but will never cause an exception to be raised.

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Answer (score -1):

I see problems with your regular expression, namely the unmatched [ character. The following works fine:

```
\|(?<month>\d{2})/(?<day>\d{2})/(?<year>\d{2})\|
```

That will group the month, day, and year results. You can then replace with the following string:

```
|$1/$2/20$3|
```

Comment: The replace string was his problem, and doesn't meet his needs. The problem occurs when you don't have the "/" characters in the replace string.